# AWS failover for on premises API

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have on premises publicly available https API. I want to create a copy of this API on AWS and create Gateway to access original API and failover to AWS version of API if healthcheck fails.
What could be the best solutions here?

I thought about Route53 but in this case I have to move DNS zone to AWS nameservers and besides if healthcheck fails switch to AWS resources is not instantaneous - several minutes. I think there should be solutions with seconds of downtime

Comment: A fallback strategy for your client might be the easiest

Answer (score 1):

Tiptoeing to AWS is certainly possible. As you mentioned, AWS Route 53 can do automatic health checks and give the IP of the healthy server to the client. The failover time depends on the TTL of the DNS record and the client configuration and is usually not in the ballpark of "within seconds".

There are basically only two solutions that fall under "failover within seconds" category:

- client failover - the client finds the healthy server
- load balancers - ever request is routed to a central server which then forwards it to a healthy server

It depends on you use cases on how you achieve these in your infrastructure. You can use AWS components (ALB, NLB) as a load balancer or have the client failover. To give advice on this, more details about the architecture and requirements are necessary.